# How to investigate tombstone crash data on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, addr2line

Occasionally users are seeing crashes in my app. The are running a signed version but I am able to get the tombstone crash data from their logcat. Trying to use the examples online to run addr2line but I need the symbols to do that.

1. Where can I find the symbols? I do not have any personal NDK code in the app. But I possibly some of the libs I use use them. This app is built on Jenkins and I don't see the symbols anywhere
2. Does the 'base.apk' indicate this is a bug in my java/kotlin code?

Tombstone (actual package name replaced with <pkg_name>:

08-10 13:53:59.693 26885 27004 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa0 in tid 27004 (Thread-22), pid 26885 (<pkg_name>.stg)
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Zebra/TC57/TC57:8.1.0/01-23-18.00-OG-U00-STD/12:user/release-keys'
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   : pid: 26885, tid: 27004, name: Thread-22  >>> <pkg_name> <<<
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xa0
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000000003  x2   0000000000000000  x3   00000079d7368918
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     x4   00000079d7368918  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000199  x11  0000000000000030
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     x12  0000000000000000  x13  ffff000000000000  x14  00000000000000ec  x15  00000079d90b2810
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     x16  00000079d91bcad0  x17  0000007a766e0680  x18  00000079d90b3010  x19  00000079d1317400
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     x20  00000079d1317408  x21  00000079d7368608  x22  00000079d59f4f38  x23  0000000000000013
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     x24  00000079d59f4fa0  x25  0000000000000000  x26  0001f2fbd8469ce3  x27  00000079d7c9eb60
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     x28  0000000000000001  x29  00000079d59f5450  x30  00000079d8ddf518
08-10 13:53:59.938 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     sp   00000079d59f4d10  pc   00000079d8e1411c  pstate 0000000020000000
08-10 13:53:59.947 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :
08-10 13:53:59.947 27700 27700 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 000000000027711c  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0000000000242514  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00000000002425cc  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0000000000244fe0  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 0000000000245478  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 0000000000245490  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00000000002503e8  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 000000000025057c  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00000000002454bc  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0000000000245974  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 000000000024a120  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 0000000000202cc0  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 00000000001e823c  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 0000000000492f1c  /data/app/<pkg_name>-ixNeuAJ0yHvNhkAJXdw0Tg==/base.apk (offset 0x440000)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 0000000000067f8c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
08-10 13:53:59.948 27700 27700 F DEBUG   :     #15 pc 000000000001f2b4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)